# SharePoint API Call function returns 401, but query works in browser

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, http-status-code-401

SharePoint API Call function returns 401, but query works in browser.
Good Day,

I am currently facing issue regarding a SharePoint Error 401. The query is able to run in the browser however, when I try to call the URL in my code it does not work.

Technically if the browser is able to get the data my code should be able to fetch the query too right? Running a get function return an 401 (Unauthorized)

*This app is calling the SharePoint Server from the client side, I have no access to the server.*

```
https://testWebsite.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27test%27
```

This is my code as follows, am I missing anything?

```
    function sharePointAPITestCall(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://testWebsite.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27test%27",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            headers: {"info1": sessionId},
            dataType: "json",
            success: async function (response) {
                const results = response.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows;

                for (const result of results) {
                    console.log(result.Cells)
                    const extension = result.Cells.find(cell => cell.Key === 'FileExtension').Value;
                    if (extension && extension.toLowerCase() !== 'aspx') {
                        const title = result.Cells.find(cell => cell.Key === 'Title').Value;
                        const url = result.Cells.find(cell => cell.Key === 'Path').Value;
                        let hitHighlightedSummary = result.Cells.find(cell => cell.Key === 'HitHighlightedSummary').Value;
                        console.log(hitHighlightedSummary)
                        try {
                            const xmlContent = await readUrlContents(url);
                            if (xmlContent) {
                                console.log(xmlContent)
                            }
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.error(error);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                if (xhr.status === 500 || xhr.status === 400) {
                    alert('Data Fetch Failed. Connect with System Administrator.');
                } else {
                    alert('Data Fetch Failed. Try again sometime.');
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you running this code from SharePoint page or from somewhere else?

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP Hello Ganesh, I am currently running this from somewhere else. I managed to fix the issue, I had to enable a domain URL configuration in my code to enable access. But right now i am facing another issue which is the CORS Policy. 
This is the error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.